# How to store the returned callable from std::bind for a pointer to a member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member, stdbind

I want to know how to declare an object of the return type of `std::function` when used with pointer to a member function:

```
int main(){

    void foo(std::string, int);
    string s = "hi";
    auto fn = std::bind(foo, s, std::placeholders::_1);
    fn(5);// ok

    /*auto fn2 = */std::bind(&std::string::empty, std::placeholders::_1); // error if I uncomment /*auto fn2 = */

    std::vector<std::string> vs{"The", "Quick", "Brown", "Fox", "Jumped", "", "Over", "The", "", "Lazy", "Dog"};
    auto it = std::find_if(vs.cbegin(), vs.cend(),
    std::bind(&std::string::empty, std::placeholders::_1)); // OK
    std::cout << "Empty string found at index: " << (it != vs.cend() ? std::distance(vs.cbegin(), it) : -1) << '\n'; // 5

    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

- If I un-comment `auto fn2 =`  I get an error:

`||=== Build: Debug in myproj (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| /home/Itachi57/Desktop/myproj/main.cxx||In function ‘int main()’:| /home/Itachi57/Desktop/myproj/main.cxx|845|  in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = bool (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::*)() const noexcept; _BoundArgs = {const std::_Placeholder<1>&}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind_helper<false, bool (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::*)() const noexcept, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type](std::placeholders::_1)’| /home/Itachi57/Desktop/myproj/main.cxx|845|internal compiler error: Segmentation fault| ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 7 second(s)) ===|`

- So Why if I call `bind` without storing its returned value using `auto` when binding a pointer to a member function is OK but I can't store that value (new callable)?
- In fact this is just for practice purpose because in real I'd prefer to use `std::mem_fn` and `std::function`.
- Update:

If I run the program from a terminal:

```
  g++ main.cxx -std=c++2a -o prog && ./prog
```

It works just fine.

I've found out that one day I've disabled "Copy-elision optimization" from CodeBlocks:

```
 -fno-elide-constructors
```

Now If I remove this and let the CodeBlocks apply it (Copy-elision opt.) the program build and works just fine!

- So does this error have a relationship with Copy-Elision Optimization? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> // error if I uncomment /*auto fn2 = */
> // OK

Actually, no, it's not okay. The C++ standard doesn't generally permit taking the address of functions defined in namespace std (be they free or members). The exceptions are always marked explicitly as addressable functions, and `std::string::empty` is not addressable.

Why? Implementation leeway and future proofing. The standard may want to add overloads. *The implementation* may want to use overloads to implement the standard-mandated behavior, or even templates. For that to be possible, and our program be well-defined by the standard, we cannot do `&std::string::empty`.

Just use lambdas to wrap standard functions that aren't addressable (as you would anyway with your own overload sets). Actually... just use lambdas and forget about `std::bind`, they are better in practically every way.

Comment: Woah. How come I hear about this for the first time today. Is there a canonical reference (outside the standardese?)

Comment: @sehe - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Other_restrictions has a summary. But it's almost word for word the standardese.

Comment: Good enough. I was only specifying to avoid the rabbit hole of a hundred scattered wordings that effectively mean something :) As long as it's in one place, that's a good reference to use in the future.

Comment: Oups ... I need to revise all my answers here where I've taken the address of misc `std::` functions... Jeez ... I've used that mainly for the `cctype` functions but I couldn't find anything about even those being ok...

Comment: In fact I prefer use `std::function` and `std::mem_fn` instead but this is just for practice purpose. I've updated the topic. Please take a look.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I'm not sure how it reflects on the `c*` headers. It's a library wide requirement, but then again... C... I vaguely recall the C standard allowing an implementation to make some functions into macros. That would break too I suppose.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa - You aren't using `std::function`. It's completely orthogonal to `std::bind`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks. I'm hoping that I've been lucky then but will try to remember to play it safe the next time.

Comment: I'd say it is less restrictive than "non permitting". "The behavior of a C++ program is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) " it **might** be OK to take the address, or it might not be OK depending on implementation.

Comment: @SergeyA - Are we here to split hairs or to write programs that will do what we except and compile successfully in portable fashion? You wanna argue it's "less bad" because explicit nasal demons are off the table? Fine, knock yourself out. It's still not permitted, and to do so is to build on quicksand.

Comment: I am not interested in splitting hairs. It is not "not permitted" by standard, it is rather that implementations is not required to support it. Those are different positions, as with implementation defined vs undefined. One can research their implementation and write code which is conformant with it.

Comment: @SergeyA - I guess it's a NLP sort of problem. When the standard says "this is addressable" it *permits* one to take its address, rather explicitly I might add. When it doesn't... it doesn't. And if you aren't interested in splitting hairs, don't follow that claim by doing just that.

Answer (score 2):

It's <strike>perfectly fine</strike>  [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817726/85371):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/954b517b5cc4adf8)**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void foo(std::string, int) {}

int main()
{
    auto fn = std::bind(&std::string::empty, std::placeholders::_1);

    std::vector<std::string> vs{"The",  "Quick", "Brown", "Fox",  "Jumped", "",
                                "Over", "The",   "",      "Lazy", "Dog"};

    auto it = std::find_if(vs.cbegin(), vs.cend(), fn);

    std::cout << "Empty string found at index: "
              << (it != vs.cend() ? std::distance(vs.cbegin(), it) : -1)
              << '\n'; // 5

    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Empty string found at index: 5

done!
```

### Simplify

I'd use `std::mem_fn`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a91d793b3f82d48)**

```
std::vector<std::string> vs{
    "The",  "Quick", "Brown", "Fox",  "Jumped", "",
    "Over", "The",   "",      "Lazy", "Dog",
};

auto it = std::find_if(vs.cbegin(), vs.cend(), std::mem_fn(&std::string::empty));

std::cout << "Empty string found at index: " << (it - vs.begin()) << '\n';
```

### Not using Bind of legacy function types:

Consider using a C++11 lambda: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e2bf913a481fc53)

```
auto it = std::find_if(vs.cbegin(), vs.cend(),
                       [](std::string const& s) { return s.empty(); });
```

Comment: But why it didn't work or me?

Comment: We can't tell. You have to show us the actual code. Consider posting it on Coliru?

Comment: Also added a simplified version with `std::mem_fn`

Comment: And added lambda as the more modern suggestion.

Comment: Actually @Storyteller-unslander-monica shared some insight that might (!!!) explain. However, my answer shows the concrete alternatives that will help.